# How to make an offset for a reference text value in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to make an offset for a cell that contains a reference for another cell. I am trying to do the offset for the other cell, and I am using the following

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(CELL("address";H3));1;1)
```

in the H3 cell there is; lets say an address for the cell `($A$7)`, I want to implement the offset at, but the value is always `0`

How can I have the value of the new offset address cell?

Comment: `CELL("address";H3)` will always return `"$H$3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional `INDIRECT(Reference;A1)` so your formula looks like so:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(INDIRECT(CELL("address";H3)));1;1)
```

If your value of cell H3 is $A$7 (it also works without dollar signs), then this formula will return the value of cell $B$8.

Comment: @maria if it did work, mark it as answer! That is what you should do at stack overflow if you get a working answer to your question. (Look for the tick icon left of the answer!)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(H3);1;1)
```

So if, say, `H3` cell contains `$A$7`, this formula will return the value of `B8`.